Problems with Cuckoo rooter
When I try to enter this command:
cuckoo rooter -g just --sudo
I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/just/.local/bin/cuckoo", line 5, in <module>
    from cuckoo.main import main
ImportError: No module named cuckoo.main

I tried to reinstall cuckoo but it doesnt help.
Running with default settings works.
